# Transform numpy array to incorporate inside arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional numpy array of dtype object, which was filled with other arrays.
As an example, here is a code reproducing that behavior:

```
arr = np.empty((3,4,2,1), dtype=object)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for k in range(arr.shape[2]):
            for l in range(arr.shape[3]):
                arr[i, j, k, l] = np.random.random(10)
```

Since all the inside arrays have the same size, I would like in this example to "incorporate" the last level into the array and make it an array of size (3,4,2,1,10).
I cannot really change the above code, so what I am looking for is a clean way (few lines, possibly without for loops) to generate this new array once created.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your problem you could use `random.random_sample()` which should give the same result:

```
arr = np.random.random_sample((3, 4, 2, 1, 10))
```

After edit the solution is `arr = np.array(arr.tolist())`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code to create this loop is locked and I do not have access to it, I just have access to the created array. Therefore, I am looking for a way to modify the already existing array instead of creating a new one in a more clever way.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll try to think of something else then!

Comment: `np.array(arr.tolist())` should be good !

Comment: It works exactly how it should, thank you! Can you edit your answer so that I can flag it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding a new `for` loop :

```
arr = np.empty((3,4,2,1,10), dtype=object)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for k in range(arr.shape[2]):
            for l in range(arr.shape[3]):
                for m in range(arr.shape[4]):
                    arr[i, j, k, l, m] = np.random.randint(10)
```

However, you can one line this code with an optimized numpy function, every random function from numpy has a `size` parameter to build a `array` with random number with a particular shape :

```
arr = np.random.random((3,4,2,1,10))
```

**EDIT :**

You can flatten the array, replace every single number by a 1D array of length 10 and then reshape it to your desired shape :

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.empty((3,4,2,1), dtype=object)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for k in range(arr.shape[2]):
            for l in range(arr.shape[3]):
                arr[i, j, k, l] = np.random.randint(10)
   
flat_arr = arr.flatten()
for i in range(len(flat_arr)):
    flat_arr[i] = np.random.randint(0, high=10, size=(10))
res_arr = flat_arr.reshape((3,4,2,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot change the loop. I can only modify it once created.

Comment: I've edited my post according to your constraint